# Having trouble with drawing 2D in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm not sure how this would work for making a 2D game, I need to draw a `Rectangle` and am not sure why it isn't showing up.  I have the `canvas` `display:` set to `none` but after running a function it is changed to display of block, so I'm not sure if that would interfere with it or not. Anyway, here is the code:

```
var gameContext = canvas.getContext("2d");
function draw() {
    gameContext.beginPath();
    gameContext.lineWidth="6";
    gameContext.strokeStyle="red";
    gameContext.rect(5,5,290,140);  
    gameContext.stroke();
}
draw();
```

Thanks for any help at all, it helps a lot!

Comment: What happens if you do not set the display to none ? Separate the issues, first have a plain canvas worknig, then show/hide it.

Comment: @GameAlchemist I think I'm having a problem with the html for it maybe?

Comment: Without the code, i cannot really comment. I was just reminding you that good old debugging principle to test one single feature at a time. Rq that you might use jsbin or jsfiddle to show your code 'alive' on S.O.  http://jsbin.com/maxiqake/1/edit?html,js,console,output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any problem with the code you have posted. In fact I ran it myself and it worked fine. Changing the display property shouldn't affect it either. Perhaps try putting a border around the canvas so you're sure the element is visible, e.g.

```
<canvas style="border: 2px solid black;"/>
```

Comment: I know that it is visible, the canvas is being drawn, but the block is not.

Comment: Isn't your post rather a comment than an answer ?

Comment: I'm not sure GameAlchemist. What if my "comment" had solved the problem? Would you consider it an answer then? Could I have posted formatted example code in a comment?

Comment: @Leirith Thanks so much! I made a mistake in the code that actually had nothing to do with what I posted! :/ Sorry for the trouble!

Comment: No trouble at all. Glad to help.